# Backup files and folders from remote host using Rsync Nodejs

Tags: node.js, cron, backup, rsync

I want to create a backup script using nodejs, cronjob. I use npm rsync to make copies of my files and folders. The code works inside the local driver, but I can't connect to the source remote host:

```
   rsync = new Rsync()
  .flags("e")
  .source("192.168.1.140:/home/test/YDA")
  .destination("../Desktop/fff/");
```

How I could provide username and password for the remote host?

Comment: Why the overhead with node? Just use your rsync command directly in cron.

Comment: @Marc I want to send emails report when the backup is done to my manager. 
Also I would like to have an Excel with backup details.